# Obtener variable php desde otro archivo

Tags: php, php5

Tengo 2 archivos PHP.

El primero se llama data.php y tiene

```
<?php

$get = $_GET;

if (isset($get['getBoxes']) && $get['getBoxes'] == 'what-we-do') {
    $boxes = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'e-commerce',
            'color' => '#ff910f',
            'content' => 'As your E-Commerce partner we will identify your specific needs, build solutions that will make your operations stronger, and provide a powerful web presence.',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'mobile & social',
            'color' => '#ffd11a',
            'content' => 'Be it iOS, Android or Windows Phone, we can accommodate your specific needs for your ideal mobile application.',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'open source cms',
            'color' => '#39a91f',
            'content' => 'Every good open-source CMS system allows for great flexibility to be customized and extended. Let us help you build yours.',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'software development',
            'color' => '#17b5ff',
            'content' => 'Our development services help you address evolving business and technology challenges by building applications tailored to meet your business requirements.',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'interactive design and usability',
            'color' => '#6b6bff',
            'content' => 'We are a full-service user interface design firm offering information architecture, interaction design, and full visual design.',
        ),
    );

    echo json_encode($boxes);
    exit;
}

if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], basename(__FILE__)) !== false) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found", 404);
    exit;
}
```

Y desde un segundo archivo PHP llamado html.php quiero usar el array $boxes pero no se como acceder a ella ya que esta dentro de $get.

Comment: No entiendo bien cómo tienes organizados tus archivos. ¿Por qué llamar a otro archivo PHP que tiene variables obtenidas por `GET`?  ¿No necesitarás más bien hacer una llamada Ajax a ese archivo? Es extraño lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Es un ejercicio que me dieron y esta armado asi. En un archivo php tengo eso que se ve en data y en otro tengo una vista html que tengo que mostrar ese array @A.Cedano

Comment: Dado que los datos están en `GET` no creo que funcione con un simple include. El archivo que invoque a `data.php` tendría que pasarle los datos con los que él debería trabajar en base al GET. Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es enviar una petición Ajax desde `html.php`, pasando a `data.php` los parámetros de lugar y recuperando su respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como te decía, este tipo de operaciones se suelen hacer a través de Ajax.

Ahora bien, tú puedes *engañar*, dicho literalmente, al archivo `data.php` del siguiente modo:

### 1. En `html.php`

Construyes un pseudo_get y luego haces el include, del siguiente modo.

```
$get=array('getBoxes'=>'what-we-do');
include('data.php');
```

### 2. En `data.php`

Tendrías que hacer una ligera modificación. Es imprescindible que comentes o borres esta línea:

```
//$get = $_GET;
```

Ya que el valor del `GET` en realidad sería enviado desde `html.php`.

---

También podrías construir *tu propia variable `$_GET`* en `html.php` del siguiente modo:

```
$_GET['getBoxes'] = 'what-we-do';
```

Sólo que en ese caso, tendrías que modificar esta línea de `data.php`:

```
if (isset($_GET['getBoxes']) && $_GET['getBoxes'] == 'what-we-do') {

    //resto del código ...
```

> Pruébalo y verás que funciona. De todos modos, repito, este no es el
>   procedimeinto normal.

Lo que demuestra esta situación es que **siempre**, en este tipo de casos, `data.php` necesitará valores desde donde se le invoca, para poder trabajar adecuadamente.

Answer (score 1):

Ya intentaste con require_once

```
require_once('data.php');
```

Según el manual de php

> Cuando se incluye un archivo, el código que contiene hereda el ámbito
>   de las variables de la línea en la cual ocurre la inclusión. Cualquier
>   variable disponible en esa línea del archivo que hace el llamado,
>   estará disponible en el archivo llamado, desde ese punto en adelante.
>   Sin embargo, todas las funciones y clases definidas en el archivo
>   incluido tienen el ámbito global. [Manual include PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)

Y según entiendo tu código $boxes se definirá dependiendo de

```
if (isset($get['getBoxes']) && $get['getBoxes'] == 'what-we-do')
```

así que si no se cumple la condición entonces $boxes no se definirá y ten cuidado con exit porque eso terminara con la ejecución del script